# Simple <input> for Camera is working on PC & Android but not iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a simple camera control in an app:

```html
<input
      style={{ display: 'none' }}
      type='file'
      accept='image/*'
      capture='environment'
      ref={inputElement}
    />
```

and I do an `inputElement.click()` to use - works on PC and Android, but doesn't open the camera on iOS with Safari. I've ensured the click is being received (the input does receive an `onClick` if I include) and I've tried a ton of different vaues for `capture` - but IOS refuses to play. Any ideas? Also, if I don't hide the input and actually click the input, the camera opens

Answer (score 0):

Because its display is none Safari might be behaving that way. You can make it hidden with fixed position to corner of the page and width and height set to 1px. I believe this will work.

Comment: Sorry, meant to mention i've tested with and without `display: none` - it still doesn't work

Comment: when it is not hidden, the programmatic click does nothing and an actual user click works